# Organize table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I need help, how to organize a table in SQL Server 2014 (one or two tables) for questions and answers, and with stored procedure return result as:

```
[{
  "question": "What is the full form of IP?",
  "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol"],
  "correct": "Internet Protocol"
}, {
  "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
  "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak"],
  "correct": "Bill Gates"
}, {
  "question": "1 byte = ?",
  "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
  "correct": "8 bits"
}, {
  "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
  "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
  "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
}, {
  "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
  "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
  "correct": "Carbon Copy"
}];
```

Comment: I typed "questionnaire database schema" into google and found many examples. Why don't you start by implementing one of these and see what issues you have. Right now, it appears that you have made no effort and you want someone to build your system for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to create a table off of what you've provided, go with these columns or something similar:
Question, Answer, Choice1, Choice2, etc.